# Remove all htaccess rule from subdirectory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, shared-hosting

I use this .htaccess file in my document root.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

I can not change my primary domain's root directory, (it is /public_html/) when I create a new subdomain it's default folder will be /public_html/subdomain so all of the .htaccess rules will be applied to it. I do not want my subdomain's folder to be affected by the .htaccess from the root directory. Is there any way I can achive this?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem by creating a .htaccess file in the directory with the following rule:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine off
</IfModule>
```

Thanks!